# Chrome still not blocking websites after this hack

Tags: google-chrome, websites

https://bytenbit.com/how-to-block-websites-on-windows-ubuntu-macintosh/

In the /etc/hosts file, I have added:

`127.0.0.1 www.youtube.com`

To block youtube. It's working for firefox now. It's working for Chrome on incognito mode. But It's not working for Chrome on regular  mode. I have restarted All windows of Chrome already.
[image]

I have cleared the Cached.

Comment: Probably Chrome stores DNS resolves in its cahce, did you try to delete the cache?

Comment: I did that after reading your comment. Still now working.

Comment: Check https://superuser.com/questions/203674/how-to-clear-flush-the-dns-cache-in-google-chrome

Comment: Is the behavior the same with: `0.0.0.0 www.youtube.com` ?

Comment: @pLumo still doesn't work after.